# GNU Recode - Properly decode mixed HTML Character/Numeric encoded text?

Tags: character-encoding, html

I recently found GNU recode as something that can be used to decode HTML entities, however when looking at a piece of malware I noticed that it appears to be mixed HTML character/entity encoding, such as this. I changed the URL from the malicious domain to example.com:

`&#x68;&#x74;&#x74;&#x70;&#x73;&colon;&sol;&sol;&#x65;&#x78;&#x61;&#x6d;&#x70;&#x6c;&#x65;&period;&#x63;&#x6f;&#x6d;&sol;`

When I pipe this into `recode html..ascii`, I get the following, which decodes the numeric entities but not the character ones.

`https&colon;&sol;&sol;example&period;com&sol;`

I'm not finding good docs on the formats handled by `recode`, is there a way I can have it do a second pass to decode the character entities also, or is there a better cli tool I can be using to decode this?

Comment: try python they have a pretty decent built-in library exactly for this